# Add city and street to personal details in Android

Tags: android

I want to make an application to add personal details to the contacts in Android. I am able to add the name, phone number, etc. using the following code:

```
intent addContactIntent = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.Insert.ACTION, Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI);
addContactIntent.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME, "myname"); 
addContactIntent.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "232323222"); 
addContactIntent.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, Contacts.Phones.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

But the problem is that in address field there is city, street, etc. and here I'm not able to add data.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit late, but hopefully still helpfull for anyone who has the same problem:

Even though [Contacts.Intents.Inserts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Intents.Insert.html) is depreciated, the [ContactsContract.Intents.Insert API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html) still doesn't provide adding city, street etc. via Intent. To solve the problem you have to do it programmatically by using the [ContactsContract API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html). Here is my solution:

First I response to some "addContactEvent" - in my case a click on a button - with a Toast. My addContactToAddressBook Method returns the Id of a String Ressource which describes the outcome of the action.

```
int resultId = addContactToAddressBook(myContactObject, this);
Toast.makeText(this, getString(resultId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Next I add a lot of information to the contact address book like street, city, name... The information is stored in a contactobject.

```
public int addContactToAddressBook(MyContactObject contact, Context context){

    // is contact already in contacts??
    if(contact != null && !numberAlreadyInContacts(contact.getPhoneNumber(), context)){

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

        // prepare Contact
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());

        // Insert First- and LastName
        if(contact.getFirstName() != null && contact.getLastName() != null){
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Lost Symbol Characters")
                .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, contact.getFirstName())
                .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, contact.getLastName())
                .build());  
        }

        // Insert Organistion and JobTitle
        if(contact.getOrganisation() != null && contact.getJobTitle() != null){
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Organization.COMPANY, contact.getOrganisation())
                .withValue(Organization.TYPE, Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .withValue(Organization.TITLE, contact.getJobTitle())
                .withValue(Organization.TYPE, Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());              
        }

        // Insert Email
        if(contact.getEmailAddress() != null){
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Email.DATA, contact.getEmailAddress())
                .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                .build());              
        }

        // Insert PhoneNumber
        if(contact.getPhoneNumber() != null){
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, contact.getPhoneNumber())
                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK)                
                .build());              
        }

        // Insert MobileNumber
        if(contact.getMobileNumber() != null){
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, contact.getMobileNumber())
                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)                
                .build());              
        }

        // Insert Address
        if(contact.getStreetAddress() != null && contact.getPostalCode() != null && contact.getLocation() != null && contact.getCountry() != null){
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, contact.getCountry())
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, contact.getPostalCode())
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.CITY, contact.getLocation())
                .withValue(StructuredPostal.STREET, contact.getStreetAddress())
                .build());              
        }

        // add to DB
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            return R.string.contact_added;

        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            return R.string.adding_contact_failed; 

        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {

            return R.string.adding_contact_failed;
        }

    } else if(contact != null && numberAlreadyInContacts(contact.getPhoneNumber(), context)){

        return R.string.contact_exists;

    } else {

        return R.string.adding_contact_failed;
    }
}
```

In this method I try to find out whether the contact is already in my address book. Therefore I look for the phone number, because it should be unique over all contacts.

```
private boolean numberAlreadyInContacts(String number, Context context) {

    if(number == null && number.length()<1){
        return false;
    }

    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

    if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
        contactLookup.close();
        return true;
    }

    contactLookup.close();
    return false;
}
```

Have fun with this code!

Chris